# Phpmailer return code 550 saying email is spam

Tags: email, spam

hi everyone i am using php mailer, but i have some issue with the code,
i give me error if i use my website image in the img src tag.
i get this error

Error : SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered. For more information, please see http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/everything-email/spam-message SMTP code: 550

the error i get is only when i am using the img src tag with images linked to my site
like
1) `<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="https://routemate.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/routemate_white_logox320x50.jpg"></td></tr>`  ------------ This Gives Error
2) `<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png"></td></tr>` --------------- this works and doesn't gives me any error or warning for SPAM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for a specific email service provider and not about programming.

Comment: I agree with Matt S, however (isn't there always a however), the solution is probably lots of fiddling and programming. Ravi has probably not done anything with his mail headers, SPF, DKIM, and the like....

Comment: That's a problem with your message content, source mail server and sending reputation, not your code.

Comment: but sir, if i use any other webisite image link their, then i am not getting any spam error, but if i use my own website img url it says it's spam email.